# c++ union to C# working class

Tags: c#, c++, unions

I only understand how unions in C++ work a little.
The first comment block i think i've duplicated in the c# class mac_const. (if not please explain why)
I'm not worried about efficiency at the moment, just that it works properly.
The second comment block I don't even know where to begin on how to translate it.
I dont get where the data[2] gets mapped to, could someone

```
//union {
//    unsigned short wd[4];
//    double data;
//    __int64 data64;
//}
//dbl_cnvt;

public class mac_const
{
    byte[] basedata = new byte[8];
    //public ushort[] wd
    public ushort this[byte index]
    {
        get { return BitConverter.ToUInt16(basedata, index * 2); }
        set { Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(value), 0, basedata, index * 2, 2); }
    }
    public double data
    {
        get { return BitConverter.ToDouble(basedata, 0); }
        set { basedata = BitConverter.GetBytes(value); }
    }
    public long data64
    {
        get { return BitConverter.ToInt64(basedata, 0); }
        set { basedata = BitConverter.GetBytes(value); }
    }
}


//union {
//    unsigned short cmd[4];
//    unsigned long data[2];
//    __int64 data64;
//}
//data_conversion;

public class data_conversion_csharp
{
    byte[] basedata = new byte[8];
    // the c++ class only 
    //public ushort[] cmd
    public ushort this[byte index]
    {
        get { return BitConverter.ToUInt16(basedata, index * 2); }
        set { Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(value), 0, basedata, index * 2, 2); }
    }
    public long[] data
    {
        // not sure what the mapping would be here, or if this should be data1 and data2 instead of an array
        ???
    }
    public long data64
    {
        ???
    }
}
```

Edit - explanation on the need for the union
@ffhighwind
Im trying to port some C++ code which makes use of unions as they should be 
I dont understand how the mapping to the second long in data occurs

```
lng_cnvt.data64 = (dbl_cnvt.data64 >> 6) + (long)0x400000000000; 

if (data < 0)
{
    lng_cnvt.data64 = -lng_cnvt.data64;
    lng_cnvt.cmd[3] = 0;
    if (lng_cnvt.data64 == (__int64)0xC00000000000)
    {
        lng_cnvt.data64 = (__int64)0x800000000000; 
        exp -= 1;
    }
}
lng_cnvt.cmd[0] = (Ushort)((lng_cnvt.cmd[0] & 0xF000) | exp);
*ldata++ = lng_cnvt.ldata[0] & 0xFFFFFFL;
*ldata++ = ((lng_cnvt.data[0] >> 24) & 0x000FFL) |                                          
    ((lng_cnvt.data[1] << 8) & 0x0FFFF00L);
```

Comment: In the second union, there is the int64  which would be an 8 byte long, The unsigned long data[2], the second long is not mapped anywhere else ... correct?

Comment: You may find this helpful: [How to: Create a C-C++ Union Type by Using Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/how-to-create-a-c-cpp-union-by-using-attributes). You aren't going to be able to accomplish this with a class, but you can do something similar with a struct.

Comment: Mr Chase, thank you. That makes the crappy class i wrote obsolete. Anyone have an idea to where the data in lng_cnvt.data[1] comes from. im pretty sure C# wont overflow into that memory,and ive posted all the relavent code from the use of that struct.

Comment: I would recommend splitting the code into separate lines and it testing out the behavior in C++. It's a left shift of 8 bits on a long.

Comment: @ffhighwind , thank you. If this was c# i already would have done that. C++ im a little uncomfortable so it never dawned on me ++.

Comment: You can simulate a union using the information in the link that @JonathonChase provided, but you really have to ask yourself - why?  Unions are a concept that had more relevance in the distant past.

Comment: Dave, i completely agree with you. I am trying to update and refresh a code base that is arcane magic. And i really need to understand it, before i shatter it and reassemble it. A major benefit of this is learning how things work and expanding my knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple if you can accept unsafe code.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
unsafe public struct lng_cnvt
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public fixed byte cmd[4];

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public fixed long data[2];

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public long data64;
}
```

CLR will treat `lng_cnvt.cmd` and `lng_cnvt.data` as pointer, and you can use indexer to access their element under an `unsafe` context. But if you can't accept unsafe code, you have to build up fixed size buffer through field declaration, then write a indexer to provide access to the right field.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public class lng_cnvt
{
    private static Dictionary<string, FieldInfo[]> arrayMembers;

    static lng_cnvt()
    {
        arrayMembers = new Dictionary<string, FieldInfo[]>();
        arrayMembers.Add("cmd", typeof(lng_cnvt).GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).
            Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("cmd")).OrderBy(y => y.Name).ToArray());
        arrayMembers.Add("data", typeof(lng_cnvt).GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).
            Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("data")).OrderBy(y => y.Name).ToArray());
    }

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    private short cmd0;
    [FieldOffset(2)]
    private short cmd1;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    private short cmd2;
    [FieldOffset(6)]
    private short cmd3;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    private long data0;
    [FieldOffset(8)]
    private long data1;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public long data64;

    public dynamic this[int index, string name = "cmd"]
    {
        get
        {
            return arrayMembers[name][index].GetValue(this);
        }
        set
        {
            arrayMembers[name][index].SetValue(this, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer and the explanation of unsafe,

Answer (score 3):

I didn't downvote but I can't comment without 50+ rep, so perhaps somebody else is in the same boat. What is the purpose of this and why couldn't you just cast to object?

Perhaps you want to limit the types that the object can contain. If so will this do?

```
class MyUnion
{
   object obj;

   MyUnion(SomeType o) { obj = o; }
   //... constructors for all accepted Types

   public object Value { get { return obj; } }
}
```

C# is managed so you can't really expect fine tuned low level controls on data. If you want fine tuned control like C++ you will need [sizeof](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.sizeof?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [unmanaged unsafe code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/index).

EDIT: Apparently you can make unions using Attributes like Jonathon Chase said.